# In SQL Server, testing a uniqueidentifier for null doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I have a stored procedure with an OUTPUT parameter as follows;

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_get_site_idx]
@site_name varchar(100),
@result uniqueidentifier output
as
begin
  select @result = [primary_idx_col] from [site] where upper([site].[site_name]) = upper(@site_name);
  if (@result is null)
  begin
    < insert a new row>
    < run the above select statement again>
  end;
end;
```

When a `@site_name` that I know does not exist is supplied, the condition `(@result is null)` is never true, in fact `@result` appears to be undefined (similar to when there's an exception in a programming language).

Table `[site]` was created as:

```
create table [site] (
[primary_idx_col] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() constraint pk_site_pk primary key,
...
);
```

Strangely, if I slightly modify the `select` statement to:

```
select @result = [primary_idx_col] from [site] where upper([site].[site_name]) = upper(@site_name) group by [primary_idx_col];
```

then `(@result is null)` will evaluate to true.

Please could you explain this behaviour? What is worng with the first `select` statement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: most likely your @result valiable is not NULL if you are calling `sp_get_site_idx` something like  `Declare @Result uniqueIdentifier
   Select @Result=NewID()   
exec sp_get_site_idx @Result output`

Comment: @bummi, your assumption is not correct! The issue is not with how the procedure is called: `declare @site_index uniqueidentifier; execute sp_get_site_idx @previously_declared_site_name, @result = @site_idx OUTPUT;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNIQUEIDENTIFIER can be checked against NULL.

I tried putting your code into a test database, and the logic seems to be working for me.

If I call your Stored Procedure with:

```
DECLARE @RESULT2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
EXEC dbo.SP_GET_SITE_IDX @SITE_NAME = '<INSERT VALUE HERE>', -- varchar(100)
    @RESULT = @RESULT2 OUTPUT;-- uniqueidentifier
SELECT @RESULT2
```

then I get the proper result depending on whether the site name is in the table or not.

Does it not insert the row in your IF, in the procedure?

Are you sure the site in question is not in your table?

It is possible that the site is in your table, but with a NULL key/value?

Comment: @Allen, thanks for your speedy reply. Without the `group by` statement, the flow never goes past the `if` condition (as if there was an exception). I'm 100% sure that the site doesn't exists as I had done a `drop table`, `create table` before running the stored proc thorough the debugger.  Also I execute this procedure exactly as you have done above: `execute sp_get_site_idx @declared_site_name @result = @site_idx OUTPUT;`

Comment: Try making an ELSE clause in the IF and printing/selecting @result into a temporary database or similar.
Verify what value result has in the IF check within the query execution might lead you to finding it.

Comment: @Allen, I've accepted your post as the answer, but can't up-vote as I don't have enough rep!!!!!

Comment: Did you figure out why you didn't hit the check?

Comment: @Allen, I don't fully understand why, but it seems that I needed to `set ANSI_NULLS ON`. So now my script is as follows: `IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.sp_get_site_idx', N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_site_idx];
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
create procedure [dbo].[sp_get_site_idx] ...`

Comment: ANSI_NULL has to do with which equality operator you can use against NULL (XXXX = NULL and XXXX IS NULL, where the latter is the prefered method).
It's usually not something to worry about, but it seems that in your situation that it has been set to off and that it messes with a NULL check.